# Push form data to a third party form

Tags: php, html, forms, joomla

I need to send form data from a form on my website (Joomla) and send some of that data to a third party form. Third party as in its someone else's website and form, I just want to direct my user there and pre fill part of that form with information they already provided on my form. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Change the action to point to the other sites page and make sure the method matches what the other page expects

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing data in the url but you have to know the name of the variables.
Maybe you can find something with the inspection mode, looking for attribute "name" of the inputs.

Comment: This answer is super vague  ...probably due to the question being super vague.